# Как сделать условие?

Tags: php

Из формы получаю данные

```
$photo1 = $_POST['photo1'];
$photo2 = $_POST['photo2'];
$photo3 = $_POST['photo3'];
```

Заполнено бывает только

`$photo1`

или

`$photo1 $photo2`

или

`$photo1 $photo2 $photo3`

```
if($photo3)
    {
        echo $photo1;
    }
```

Если заполнено только `$photo1` то вывести только `$photo1`

Если заполнено только `$photo1 и $photo2` то вывести только `$photo1 и $photo2`

Если заполнено только `$photo1 и $photo2 и $photo3` то вывести только `$photo1 и $photo2 и $photo3`

Comment: Просто сделайте три if вложенных друг в друга, например?

Comment: В каком порядке?

Comment: А как вообще `И` использовать? `if($photo1 and $photo2)`?

Comment: м.... Вы пишите: если заполнено фото1 - вывести фото1, если заполнено фото1 и фото2 - вывести фото1 и фото2, если заполнено фото1, фото2 и фото3 - вывести их все. По-моему у вас вообще нужно вывести любое фото, если оно заполнено.

Comment: нет, там код разный будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начинайте с максимально строгого условия, т.е. проверяйте все три фото и дальше по убыванию, т.к. вы не можете проверить изначально `$photo1` и не проверить остальные, ибо может возникнуть ситуация, когда вы вывели `$photo1`, но так же присутствуют `$photo2` или `$photo3`.

```
if (!empty($photo1) && !empty($photo2) && !empty($photo3)) {
    // output of $photo1, $photo2, $photo3
} elseif (!empty($photo1) && !empty($photo2)) {
    // output of $photo1, $photo2
} elseif (!empty($photo1)) {
    // output of $photo1
} else {
    // no one photo was given
}
```

Ниже приведен код, его тоже интересно рассмотреть, т.к. такой вариант вам по приведенному условию не подходит, причина тому, что в результирующий массив с фото, могут попасть варианты `[$photo2, $photo3]` или же `[$photo1, $photo3]`.

```
$output = array_filter(
    [
        $_POST['photo1'] ?? '',
        $_POST['photo2'] ?? '',
        $_POST['photo3'] ?? ''
    ],
    static function(mixed $photo) {
        return !empty($photo);
    }
);
```

Подводя итоги, в вашем случае, перебор с помощью управляющей конструкции `if-elseif-else` наиболее подходящий.

Comment: Спасибо, всё ок. Если больше количество `photo` будет, можно же будет по аналогии `elseif` делать

Answer (score -2):

сложить ключи в массив и обработать

```
$keys = ['photo1', 'photo2', 'photo'];
foreach ($keys as $key) {  
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) {
        echo $_POST[$key];
        $$key = $_POST[$key];  // $photo1 = ...
    }
}
```

Если вам уж прям нужны переменные `$photo1, ..` то `$$key` в помощь

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит по условию вопроса, т.к. в результирующий массив могут попасть варианты `[$photo2, $photo3]` или же `[$photo1, $photo3]`.

Comment: @Borislav по условию задачи не может прийти пара `2-3` или `1-3`.